# Why does border-separate: collapse break bordered tables in Bootstrap[?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a bordered table, using the Bootstrap classes `table table-bordered`. If I add `border-collapse: separate`, the borders are separated correctly, but the top and bottom ones become zero width and so invisible.

Is this a quirk of Bootstrap, or am I doing something wrong? If so, what's the right approach?

```css
.table-bordered {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap test</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <container>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered m-5">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Box</td>
              <td rowspan=2>Big box</td>
              <td>Box</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Box</td>
              <td>Box</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </container>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap css `border-width: 1px 0` so that you need to overnight it

```css
.table-bordered {
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.table-bordered td {
  border-width: 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap test</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <container>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered m-5">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Box</td>
              <td rowspan=2>Big box</td>
              <td>Box</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Box</td>
              <td>Box</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </container>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can do that, but how come the table has all the borders when I don't use `border-collapse: separate`?